# C'est quoi l'explication étymologique du "c" au milieu de "coincer" ?

Tags: verbes, étymologie, orthographe, phonétique, linguistique

Bonjour, j'ai une question très, très "niche" à vous poser. Pourquoi y-a-t-il un deuxième 'c' dans le verbe "coin**c**er" alors qu'il est basé sur le mot "coin" ? Autrement dit, pourquoi ne s'écrit-il pas "coiner" sans le c (ni le son /s/) au milieu ?

Et avant que quelqu'un ne¹ fasse remarquer le cas du mot "cogner" que l'étymologie rattache étroitement à "coincer" et qui, contrairement à celui-ci, ne contient pas de 'c'/[s], ça ne résout pas cette énigme en soi. En effet, pour un verbe dérivé de "coin" (ou du moins de la même source), mon avis est que "cogner" ressemble à ce à quoi je me serais attendu étant donné la morphologie et la phonologique du français (i.e. racine + désinence *-er* ; /n/ → /ɲ/ régulièrement) plus que "coin**c**er" n'y ressemble. Mais alors, si aucun 'c'/[s] ne se trouve dans "coin" ou dans "cogner" (les deux mots auxquels "coincer" est le plus étroitement apparenté) ... d'où vient-il donc ? Je n'en ai pas la moindre idée !

Je veux clarifier que je comprends bien le sens de "coincer" - c'est
seulement sa curieuse orthographe qui me rend perplexe et fasciné. S'agit-il d'une trace de la forme latine originale ou bien d'un mystère linguistique qui n'est tout simplement pas possible d'élucider ?

Certes, cette question est assez insignifiante dans le grand ordre des choses, mais je me le demande depuis trop longtemps pour ne pas essayer de trouver une réponse. Merci d'avance pour toute aide que vous pourrez me donner.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Point de grammaire aléatoire : inclure le 'ne' ou non ? Je n'en suis jamais tout à fait sûr.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cette réponse était un commentaire à la réponse de livresque, mais il est devenu suffisamment longue et comprenait suffisamment d'informations nouvelles que j'ai décidé d'en faire une réponse.

L'explication de Delphine Tribout est fondée d'un point de vue synchronique, mais reste insatisfaisante au niveau diachronique: La plupart des paires de la liste de Tribout contiennent un /t/ ou un /k/ palatalisé (hausser < al**ti**are; lancer < lan**ce**are, sauf tabasser (que le TLFi explique comme étant une variante de tapper + un suffixe argotique -ass-), plisser et coincer, où le /s/ est un véritable ajout non-étymologique.

Ce genre d'épenthèse est assez fréquente en français contemporain, qui tend à fournir une consonne à tous les mots se terminant par une voyelle une fois qu'on les suffixe. Cependant, la consonne épenthétique est presque systématiquement /t/ ou /n/ (après les voyelles nasales uniquement) : chouchou -> chouchou**t**er, dodo -> dodo**t**er, queue -> équeu**t**er, cancan /kɑ̃kɑ̃/ -> cancaner /kɑ̃ka**n**e/. Les entorses à ce schéma sont souvent motivées par la rareté de la séquence ainsi produite (banlieue -> banlieu**s**ard, /øt/ étant rare alors que /øz/ est très fréquent. Dans le même genre, bleu a donné à la fois bleuté et bleusaille) ou l'attraction de mots similaires (bazar -> bazarder alors que bazarer aurait été très bien formé, par influence de paires comme bavard - bavarder, tard - tarder, cafard - cafarder, ou encore congolais et togolais, formés sur le modèle de sénégalais).

Bref, qu'est-ce qui a mené à la création de plisser et de coincer plutôt qu'à celle des réguliers "pliter" ou "coiner" ? On peut directement trouver un problème avec la rime /wan/, extrêmes rare dans les termes natifs du français (c'est /waɲ/ ou /ɔɲ/ qu'on retrouve à la place: soin - soigne, poing - empoigner et se pogner), qui aurait pu mener à des solutions de remplacement.

La première attestation de plisser citée par le TLFi est de 1538, celle de coincer de 1773. Plisser est suffisamment ancien pour que le suffixe pluriel ait pu l'influencer, mais pas coincer.

Le [FEW](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/59335) signale une forme en -t- *cointer* dans le sud-ouest de la France (Poitou, Angoulême, "Bgât"), mais la version en /s/ (ou un dérivé du /k/ palatalisé) semble être majoritaire pour les équivalents de coincer dans les cousines du français. D'autres dérivés de *cuneum* présentent un /s/: écoinçon ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9coin%C3%A7on)) qui date du 14e siècle et le normand écoinc(h)eter (ébrécher).

Le FEW discute d'ailleurs brièvement de la consonne épenthétique, mais ne nous offre aucune solution: "*cogner* ist in einer zeit gebildet worden, da das stammauslautende ñ noch seinen nasal-palaten charakter hatte. Bei der neubildung des verbums von kwɛ̃ aus war ein fugekonsonant nötig; als solcher trat fast durchwegs s, in einigen gegenden t ein. Daher *coincer*" (*Cogner* a été formé à une époque où le son ñ de la racine conservait son caractère nasalo-palatal. Lors de la formation nouvelle d'un verbe à partir de /kwɛ̃/, une consonne-joint a été nécessaire ; en cette qualité, /s/ apparaît de manière consistante, /t/ dans certaines régions, d'où *coincer*).

Pour *plisser*, une note de [l'entrée *plicare* du FEW (page 74)](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/73852) indique: "Dieses verbum ist offenbar vom plural von *pli* abgeleitet. Vielleicht hat auch das vorbild van *plais*: *plassier* (gesprochen plę: plęse) eingewirkt, s. **plaxus*. Aus dem fr. entlehnt ndl. *plisseeren*" (Ce verbe est manifestement dérivé du pluriel de *pli*. Peut-être le modèle de *plais* - *plaissier* (prononcé /plɛ/ - /plɛse/) a-t-il également agi (v. *plaxus). Au français a été emprunté le néerlandais *plisseren*)

Et c'est là que mes recherches m'ont mené, sans réponse définitive quand à la source du /s/ de coincer. L'existence de dérivés de coin présentant également un /s/ comme écoinçon et écoinceter des siècles avant la première attestation de coincer me fait suspecter qu'il a existé une "lignée fantôme" utilisée à l'oral ou dans les langues régionales remontant à une racine /kwɛnts/ (un pluriel également ?) en ancien français, mais ça ne fait que repousser le problème dans le temps.

Answer (score 3):

Les premières occurrences du verbe *coincer*, à l'origine un terme spécifique au vocabulaire de la marine, montrent une orthographe hésitante : *coincer*, *coinser* ou *coinsser*.

Les définitions indiquent en général l'utilisation de plusieurs *coin**s*** utilisés pour *coinsser un mât*.

On peut alors émettre l'hypothèse que ce /s/ médian pourrait être un reliquat de la marque du pluriel qui était peut-être encore prononcée par les marins lors de l'émergence de ce verbe.

Note: Ce dernier paragraphe n'est que pure spéculation.

---

Edit:

Spéculation clairement infondée. [@Livresque](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/46805/1109) puis [@Eau qui dort](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/46809/1109) ont fourni de bonnes explications et pistes, en particulier la paire *élan* - *élancer* et le mot *écoinçon*.

Comment: Je mets +1 juste pour l'edit qui est un bel exemple pour ceux qui restent coincés sur leurs positions - aussi infondées soit-elles.  Mais bien sûr je préfère la réponse de livresque (déjà plussoyée).

Answer (score 3):

C'est une **consonne épenthétique**, sémantiquement vide.  La phonologie peut tout mener; *coiner n'est pas aussi chantant que coincer.

Pour ce qu'il y a de l'étymologie de [coincer](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?12;s=3960705900;r=1;nat=;sol=1;) (TLF):

> Étymol. et Hist. 1. 1773 coinser « fixer, caler avec des coins »
> (BOURDÉ, Man., I, 127 ds Fr. mod., t. 25, p. 308 : Coinser les Mâts);

Le nom *[coin](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coin)* vient du latin classique *cuneus* comme [cogner](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cogner) et le verbe *cuneare*.  Je pensais à l'inchoatif peut-être ou l'effet du pluriel comme @jllaigre mais après tout, c'est phonologique.  Il s'agit de **l'épenthèse**, l'apparition d'un son au milieu d'un mot qui n'est pas lié à l'étymologie mais qui rend souvent la prononciation plus naturelle.

Dans la thèse *Les conversions de nom à verbe et de verbe à nom en
français* ([HAL](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01577528/document) Tribout), l'auteur donne une explication de l'identité phonologique de la conversion et cite le nom *coin* et le verbe *coincer* dans cette catégorie des paires nom-verbe.

> Définition 6 : Consonne épenthétique 
> La consonne finale d’un lexème est épenthétique si : 
> a. elle n’est pas présente graphiquement, 
> b. elle n’est pas réalisée dans la forme citationnelle du lexème,
> c. elle est réalisée lors de certaines dérivations.

De la table *Conversions avec épenthèse en fonction de la
consonne épenthétique* (p. 132) on voit les paires avec **/s/** où se trouve notre coin et d'autres exemples :

> **coin∼coincer**, désintérêt∼désintéresser, effort∼efforcer, élan∼élancer,
> intérêt∼intéresser, mordant∼mordancer, pli∼plisser, rehaut∼ rehausser,
> renfort∼renforcer, roman∼romancer, tabac∼tabasser

Donc (a) *coin* n'est pas *coinc, (b) le suffixe -cer n'appartient pas au lexème *coin* et (c) le son /s/ se réalise en *c* dans le verbe dérivé du nom.

Citations :
Delphine Tribout. Les conversions de nom à verbe et de verbe à nom en français. Linguistique.
Université Paris Diderot (Paris 7), 2010. Français. fftel-01577528f